# React - How to use files metadata in state for miltiple files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use metadata from files ( like name, size etc ) to create a div's with this data.
In pure js i have this done but i'm learning react.
What is the most elegant and modern way to extract those data in react?
I tried use react methood called .map but this code give me error.

Thank you in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import Map from './components/map/map';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header/header';
import UploadHandler from './components/upoloadHandler/uploadHandler';
import CardsWrapper from './components/cardsWrapper/cardsWrapper';
import fileHandler from './components/upoloadHandler/fileHandler.js';

const initialStateItems = [];

class App extends React.Component{
  state = {
    items: [...initialStateItems],
  }

addItem = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const files = e.target.files;
  let newItem;
  files.map(file => {
    newItem = file.name;
  });



  this.setState(prevState => ({
    items: [...prevState.items, newItem]
  }));
};

render(){
  return (
    <div className="pageWrapper">
      <Header />
      <Map />
      <UploadHandler submitFn={this.addItem} />
      <CardsWrapper
          items={this.state.items}
      />
    </div>
  )};
}
export default App;
```

```
TypeError: files.map is not a function
App.addItem
C:/Users/Slav/Desktop/dev/geoloc/src/App.js:21
  18 | e.preventDefault();
  19 | const files = e.target.files;
  20 | let newItem;
> 21 | files.map(file => {
     | ^  22 |   newItem = file.name;
  23 | });
  24 | 
View compiled
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json` file to hold your meta data.

Example:
data.json - file

import data from './data.json';

and if you hold in `data.json` array, you can use data.map()

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `event.target.files` is not of type `Array` and does not implement `map` function.

It's of type `FileList` and you can use a simple `for` loop to iterate over it.